# Angularjs number filter not working properly with ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angularjs` number filter in `angular-ui-grid`. In a grid, the filter works fine. But when I export the grid to `csv` and open into excel, it does not work properly.

I've added the filter in `exporterFieldCallback` as well.

In a grid: `cellFilter: 'number:6', type: 'number'` and in `exporterFieldCallback`:

```
if(col.name == 'columnName'){                   
                    return $filter('number')(input,6);
                }
```

The numbers are displayed with 6 decimal places on a grid. But while I export it to `csv` and open into excel, the zeros are truncated.

Please find [this plunker of angularjs number filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/jQx0zpRJLHndL2VMSGOr?p=preview) where numbers are displayed with specified fractionSize which is also works fine in grid. But does not work same while export the grid.

If value in a grid is `3.000000` then in excel it shows `3` only.
If value in a grid is `1.415400` then in excel it shows `1.4154` only.

**Why zeros are truncated while `angular-ui-grid` is exported to `csv` and open it in excel ? How do I display values in excel as same as it appears on a grid ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an Excel issue, rather than an AngularJS one.

When you open a CSV file in Excel, it looks for numbers and normalises them, removing leading and trailing zeros. You can (hopefully) see that your CSV file is correct by opening it in a text editor instead and checking that it has leading and trailing zeros.

Depending on how often you'll need to be importing data into Excel, there are a couple of different options, but as you just want values to 6 decimal places, the simplest is probably to import the data and then reformat it within Excel using the Increase Decimal option: [image: Increase Decimal button in Excel]